# How does std::index_sequence_for<T... >() exactly work?

Tags: c++, c++17, template-meta-programming, index-sequence

I have the following code

```
#include<iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include<utility>
using namespace std::literals::string_literals;


template< typename tupleType, size_t ... inds >
void printTupleH(const tupleType& tuple, std::index_sequence<inds ...>){

    ((std::cout << std::get<inds>(tuple) << " "), ..., (std::cout << "\n"));
}


template< typename ... tupleElementsTypes>
void printTuple(const std::tuple<tupleElementsTypes ...>& tuple){

    printTupleH< std::tuple<tupleElementsTypes ...>, std::index_sequence_for<tupleElementsTypes... >()  >(tuple, std::index_sequence_for<tupleElementsTypes...>() );
}


int main() {
    auto myTuple{std::make_tuple(1, 0.5, "erfevev"s, "dsfgsfgsf",'g',true,0x44,999999999999999999,9.999999999)};

    printTuple(myTuple);

}
```

I don't know what's wrong with this

```
printTupleH< std::tuple<tupleElementsTypes ...>, std::index_sequence_for<tupleElementsTypes... >()  > As the IDE says.
```

When I leave the function call without any template args the deduction works well.

What I know is `std::index_sequence_for<tupleElementsTypes... >()` should expand to `0,1,2,..N-1` . So what's wrong.

Comment: Notice that in C++17, you might do `std::apply([](const auto&... args){ (std::cout << args << " "), ..., (std::cout << "\n"); }, myTuple);`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`printTupleH`'s template definition expects a list of `std::size_t`. `std::index_sequence_for` creates a single [`std::integer_sequence`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence) (more precisely, a  `std::index_sequence`, which is just an alias for integer sequences of `std::size_t`), not a list of sizes.

To explicitly add the deduction you would need to manually provide a list of `std::size_t`, one for each index – which defeats the point of using an index sequence in the first place! It is intended to be used with template deductions.